# How to create a relation to view collection in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Let's say that I have the following database structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Entity (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   (...)
);

CREATE VIEW View_Entity AS
SELECT ID, (some additional data)
FROM Entity
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (...);

CREATE TABLE Data (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   (...)
);

CREATE TABLE EntityData(
    EntityID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Entity(ID),
    DataID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Data(ID)
);
```

The database was created in EF Code-First. So the entities looks like:

```cs
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id;

    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

Long story short:

- Entity to Data relation is *..*
- For every Entity there is exactly one View_Entity and they share the same primary key

My question is: is it possible to create an access from Data to collection of `View_Entity` using already existing database infrastructure (including the `EntityData` table)?

I'd need something like:

```cs
public class Data 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id;

    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<View_Entity> View_Entities { get; set; }
}
```

However after changing model this way, EF migration mechanism makes changes like if `View_Entity` was just another table with 1..* relation.

I need to somehow tell EF to use `EntityData` as an intermediary table to pick data from `View_Entity`, but I have no idea how.